# Unity build error after creating signing key

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-console

I'm building my app for android.
I have set things like: company name, product name, package name, version, bundle version code and after generationg keystore I have this error:

```
Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:\Users\err\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\26.0.0\apksigner.bat', CommandLine='sign --ks "C:/DATA/unity/Jet/Jet/Roc.keystore" --ks-pass stdin  --ks-key-alias "roc" --key-pass stdin  "C:\DATA\unity\Jet\Jet\Temp/StagingArea/Package.apk"', CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea'
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ()
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()
UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start (System.EventHandler exitCallback) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/Program.cs:44)
UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/Program.cs:28)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.RunWithStdin (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg, System.String[] input)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg, System.String[] stdin)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildAPK.SignPackage (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildAPK.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:271)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

I have no clue how to fix it. Than I tried to follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eJ13SpxqeM but still I get the same error.